# Print doesnt work if i set my python exe as default app

Tags: python, windows, printing

I made a small Python script to automatically prints files if you open the file with my program, which works. For my task I want to print every pdf file I open, so I set my exe as default app to open pdf files. But as soon as I set the exe as default it wont work anymore and I can't figure out why.

The Errormessage:

> Traceback: (most recent call last):
>
> File "AutomaticPrint.py", line 11, in <module>
>
> OSError: [WinError 1155] No application is associate with the specified file for this operation 'C:\\Users\....myfile.pdf'
>
> [23124] Failed to execute script 'AutomaticPrint' due to unhandled exception

Here is my Code:

```
1 from sys import argv
2 from os import startfile, system
3 import time
4
5
6
7 #print(argv[1])
8
9
10
11 startfile(argv[1], "print")
12
13
14
15 time.sleep(5)
16
17
18
19 system("TASKKILL /F /IM AcroRD32.exe")
```

Comment: Probably there simply isn't an application entered for the "print" verb for PDF files.

Comment: `os.startfile` runs the file with its associated application. Since you changed default app for PDFs, an "associated app" is now your program, and because it is not able to handle "print" operation, you get an error.

Comment: @matszwecja thank you for answering so fast! do you know what i could do to fix that ?